# How to make Only Video Rotate to Landscape in SwiftUi

Tags: swiftui, rotation, accelerometer, landscape-portrait

I have a view where the video is at the top. When I rotate to landscape, I only want the video to go full screen. Can anyone help me do that. Is there a native way to make this happen in Swiftui?

[image]

Comment: I'd like to know as well? Can StackOverflow please help?

Comment: Any chances you solved it, guys?

Comment: Showing some code would help. You'd probably need to use .fullscreenCover() to show a video full screen.